# How would I separate a sentence into individual words with a loop and send them individually into an ArrayList in Java?

Tags: java

I have a very specific problem for my CS course. I have a sentence in a string, and I need that separated into individual words within an ArrayList, and cannot use the split method.

The issue I have is that I have had zero teaching on arrays, only the bare minimum teaching for loops and String statements. I've done a lot of research and figured out the best way to go about making the loop, and sending the words to the ArrayList, however I still can't find a good way to actually have it loop through the sentence and separate each individual word at all. I get how easily it can be done to separate the very first word, however after that I get lost. I have no idea how to make the loop for its other iterations specifically grab the next word in the sentence after the one it previously got.
(Note: The only utilities imported are Scanner, File, HashMap, ArrayList, Random, and *)

What I'm looking for is any tips of specific methods I should try and employ or research. Or perhaps a set of code that is fairly functional in doing something similar to what I'm looking for that I can look at and build my own code off of.

Comment: Also I don't need to remove any punctuation, and currently my ideas stem from using the spaces between words and using indexOf to figure out when a new word begins/a word ends.

Comment: Once you get the first word, add that to the ArrayList, remove it from the sentence, and repeat. Please show us the code you have, and it will be easier to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you said the word "word"(That's weird) I assume that they are separated by spaces. If you are reading in the inputs, then just use `Scanner`... Then:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
ArrayList<String> words = new ArrayList<String>();
for(int i = 0;i<numberOfWord;i++){
   words.add(input.next());// .next() method read data that are separated by space
}
```

or:

```
String theLineOfWord;//Given to you

StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(theLinOfWord);//Used to separate words.
ArrayList<String> words = new ArrayList<String>();

while(st.hasMoreTokens()){
    words.add(st.nextToken();
}
```

or:

```
public static ArrayList<String> getWords(String line){
        ArrayList<String> words = new ArrayList<String>();
        line += " ";//add a space to ignore the ending case 
        
        while(line.length() != 0) {
            words.add(line.substring(0, line.indexOf(' ')));//add the word to the list
            line = line.substring(line.indexOf(' ') + 1, line.length());//take out the useless string away
        }
        return words;
    }
```

Comment: So for my assignment, the String that holds the sentence is created in a separate method and passed down to this method so the first option I cannot use. Also I am not allowed to import other java utilities like the StringTokenizer, so it did not work either. Thanks for the help though, gave me a few ideas to try anyways.

Comment: @pxlbrandon Ok, check my answer again now, cuz I added another way.

Comment: That looks a lot close to what I was thinking of. Not quite exactly what I needed, but I didn't want a full direct answer anyways. Gonna try a few things with that last method you gave, and get back to you if it doesn't work, or mark your response as the answer if I am able to eventually get it working for me. Thanks!